# Web3.js filtering on allEvents

Tags: web3js, filters

I'm struggling to figure out how to add a filter to allEvents requests.

My current code:

```
const contract = getState().web3Reducer.get('contract');
          contract.getPastEvents('allEvents', {
              filter : { owner: '0x3333333....333' },
              fromBlock: currentBlock - 5760,
              toBlock: 'latest'
          }).then(transactions => dispatch(eventsFetched(events)));
```

It seems like web3 doesn't support such call, any idea how to get around this? I could fetch all events and filter in Javascript, but feels very wrong.